# Cygwin: PS1 cannot wrap lines on the same line (2)

Tags: cygwin, console

I found that in my cygwin,

The PS1 console have 2 lines and I want to solve it. This is due to "\n" at the end of PS1
But I cannot export it well due to "not a valid identifier" error.

How can I solve this? Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `export`, you don't use the dollar sign.

So it's `export PS1=Hello World`, not `export $PS1=Hello World`.

Comment: Thx...it's just my poor linux knowledge