# How can I remove new line character in prompt?

Tags: bash, cygwin, prompt

As you can see in the screenshot, I have an unneeded newline character in my prompt. Anyone know how to do remove this character from my prompt?

[image]

Comment: Then stop pressing Enter?

Comment: -1, this is not a diagram, and this question means nothing.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you mean?

Comment: @Ravachol Please use comments to provide constructive guidance to help the OP provide enough information

Comment: The thing is that the questioner _knows_ the answer to the question as it is asked.  Xe stated it in [this almost identical question that xe asked three hours earlier](http://superuser.com/questions/379719/).

Comment: @JdeBP: the problem is not the same as before. this one a extra newline character is generated when I press "Enter". But before, it is a new line character in the PS1

Comment: @KitHo: Your prompt is printed when you press "Enter".  That's where the new-line character is coming from.  What is the output of `echo "$PS1"`?  Incidentally, your screenshot is difficult to read; I had to download a copy of the image to see the extra empty lines clearly.  A textual copy-and-paste would have demonstrated the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "new line character" is part of your Bash *prompt*, kept in the `$PS1` variable:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \$ '
```

Remove it and put the updated PS1 in your `~/.bashrc`.

See [Customizing bash prompt](https://www.google.com/search?q=customizing+bash+prompt) for further information.

Comment: That's great!, how do you my PS1 having the \n?

Comment: @Kit: I guessed.